# htaccess Rewrite with Colons in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess looks like that

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} go/(.+)/?$
RewriteRule ^go/([^/]*)/?$ go/test.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So a url like
*mydomain.com/go/sitename* will be correctly routed to */go/test.php?name=sitename*

However, if my url looks like that (the numbers are used as identifier), I get a "access denied" message in my browser:
*mydomain.com/go/sitename::123*
This always happens if colons (**:**) are included in the url. What can I do to use urls with colons?

UPDATE:
This Problem (access denied) only occurs, if there is existing a directory with the same name, in my case: /go

But I have always a directory with the same name.

Comment: Oh, I see. I read the string with php and extract the numbers behind the two colons in order to select the right row in my mysql table. so sitename::101 means that I select row 101. Would sitename:101.html be correct?

Comment: Are you adding those colons or is something else doing it? What framework are you using?

Comment: No framework. I am adding those colons. And it doesnt even work if I use a url like mydomain.com/go/sitename::123.html